# Wordpress .htaccess Redirection: How can I make own "details-pages"?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to use an own url for each set in a database-table (Like example.com/detail/user1). Same as the Product links in woocommerce for example. But I don't know how to do that.

At the moment I'm using this:

`RewriteRule ^detail/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ getdetail/?username=$1 [R0301, L]`

But it always redirect to the page "getdetail". And I would like if the url is ".../detail/user1" and the content of ".../getdetail/?username=user1". Like the Products in WooCommerce

I hope you can help me

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve?

Comment: I have a table of a Database with entries. And I would like to write for example example.com/fruit/apple in the browser and then i get a site where are details about apples and same thing with pineapple or other fruits. I don't want to make static pages

Comment: How about:
`RewriteRule ^fruit/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ showFruit/?fruit=$1 [R0301, L]`

Comment: It's actually what I have, but wordpress redirect to this page. And don't show only the content.
I think it should be like here. you have a question and the url has the title in the question. But it's not a created page. It's just a page which shows the entry XXXX of the table from the database

Comment: You would need directory `showFruit` with `index.php` for it to work. Or if you want it handled in wordpress then you need to add custom handler for `showFruit` registered with your wordpress installation, so that wordpress knows what to do when such page in requested. Afair by default wordpress has something like `RedirectRule .* /index.php` in top level directory, so any attempt at redirecting anything else will end up in index.php anyway.
You should probably add static page, with custom php content or do it via plugin.

Comment: @bezet I don't know what you mean. How I've to do this?